# Creating a histogram in R knowing bin heights

Tags: r, histogram, bins

I'm trying to make a histogram in R in a sort of backwards manner, where I already know how many bins I want, and how many observations are in each bin. My data looks like this

| Interval | 0-2 | 2-4 | 4-6 | 6-10 | 10-15 | 15-25 | >25 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Number of observations | 6 | 9 | 7 | 9 | 6 | 7 | 5 |

I have the data saved in the format `obs<-c(6,9,7,9,6,7,5)`. But trying to run `hist(obs)` of course creates a histogram which counts how many of the bins have between 5-6 observations, how many between 6-7, and so on, which is the opposite of what I want.

I tried using barplot, but it comes out looking wierd. Is there a way to use a `hist`-style plot, where I specifically get the bins

(-∞, 2], (2,4], (4,6], ..., (25,∞)?

with the respective heights 6, 9, 7, 6, 7, 5?

Comment: What you are describing is a really just a bar chart, not a histogram. How is your data stored in R? It would be easier to help if you provided data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) such as a `dput()` to make it more clear. You seem to be using base R so try `barplot`. Maybe you can say more about what exactly is "weird" about the barplot and show how you are calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a one-liner after having the data set read in.

```
barplot(as.matrix(df1[-1]))
```

[image]

---

### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Interval    0-2     2-4     4-6     6-10    10-15   15-25   >25
'Number of observations'    6   9   7   9   6   7   5
", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use ggplot, you could go for: geom_col()

e.g.

```
ggplot(data_table, aes(x=obseration_class, y=value_of_class)) + geom_col()
```